# how to disable defalut URl showing when overing on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Please refer below image

[image]

when ever am handovering it shows some URl in  window Bottom of IE browser. but no url supplied for this button.

This is the button  code

```
<button id="btnCancel"  >Cancel</button>
```

How can i remove the invalid URL ? why it showing in IE browser ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Button itself doesn't show any URL, you can verify it by creating an empty page with just the `<button>` HTML. There will be no URL showing in IE. Then you will have to find out, what's causing the URL to be displayed. Or post some minimal code, where it behaves like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not something you can ask to client Browser so there is not an *official* method. Fortunately there are few workarounds.

Let's first see how it's usually done with links:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#" data-href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myLink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            window.location.href = $("#btnCancel").data("href");
            return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

Internet Explorer shows same link for `submit` buttons too when they're in a `<form>` (and of course target URL is combination of - resolved - `target` and `action` attributes). Moreover don't forget that default for `type` attribute in `<button>` is `submit`.

### Solutions

First possible solution is to do not use `<button>` but `<input type="button">` to do the trick: IE won't display target URL and you can manually submit your form with JavaScript.

If you need advanced *formatting* provided by `<button>` then you can apply same technique: use buttons of type `button` instead of `submit` (the default) and IE won't display any tooltip.

HTML (if you need to keep `<button>` element):

```
<button id="btnCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

Or (if content is just a plain string):

```
<input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel"></input>
```

Or (if you're using Bootstrap and you want to use a link):

```
<a id="btnCancel" class="btn" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnCancel").click(function (e) {
            myForm.submit(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Always specify the type attribute for a "button" element. Different browsers use different default types for the "button" element. 
If you do not specify the "type" in button element, browser assumes it a "submit" type and use enclosing "form" element action of the button element.
Please refer below link for reference-
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp